# Rails Scope - Get all Products where ProductCategories.size > 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model, scope

I have a simple three way model association where a `Product` can belong to multiple `Categories`.

```
Product has_many ProductCategories

ProductCategories belongs_to Product
ProductCategories belongs_to Category

Category has_many ProductCategories
```

I'm trying to create a scope that returns all `Products` that have `visible=true` and also **at least** one associated `ProductCategories`.

How would this scope look like?

Here's what I've tried:

```
scope :visible, -> { where(visible: true).where(product_categories.size > 0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your *product.rb*:

```
scope :visible, -> { where(visible: true).joins(:product_categories).uniq }
```

It should generate this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.* FROM products
  INNER JOIN product_categories ON product_categories.product_id = products.id
```

Or, in English: “return all products that have at least one product category”. Note that products with multiple product categories will show up multiple times and hence we used `uniq` to have `DISTINCT` query.